# Citation issue, author comma date

Tags: lyx, citing

I've had a good search around Internet but can't really find anything relevant to what I'm looking for.

In Lyx, when selecting a citation options the style closest to what I need is:

> (Author, Date)

As per my universities referencing guidelines, all citations such as this should be:

> (Author Date)

omitting the comma.

I am using the authordate1.bst, however I have tried 1 through 4 to see if they made any difference.

I did wonder if any of this code here (from the file named above) is responsible.  I toyed around with it but noticed no difference, is it just for the bibliography rather than citations?

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { t "others" =
                { ", {\em et~al.\ }\relax" * }
                { ", \& " * t * }                           %  Butcher, pages
              if$                                           %  186-189.
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}
```

Is this citation style even defined by the .bst file, or is it something hard coded into Lyx?

**Edit:**
Problem solved (thanks @TorbjørnT.)

As said, adding this to the preamble solved the problem, assuming you are using natbib (Bibliography settings > Citation style).

```
\setcitestyle{aysep={ }}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you posted a complete MWE (minimum working example) that shows what you've done so far. In particular, it would be helpful to show which citation command(s), which citation-management package (if any), and which particular bibliography style file you're using.

Comment: Assuming you use Natbib (an option in the bibliography settings), try adding `\setcitestyle{aysep={ }}` to the document preamble (Document -> Settings -> LaTeX preamble).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using default lyx settings. So, @TorbjørnT. yes I am using Natbib. I tried adding this line to the preamble, however it resulted in an error informing me I have forgotten a '}', which I did not have before (these are errors caused when trying to render references with that line in preamble).

Comment: Works fine here, with Natbib and Author-year style chosen in bibliography settings, and authoryear1 (or 2, or plainnat) as bibliography style. Edit: Not very helpful, so perhaps you could try creating a minimal document to find out what causes the error.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks. I haven't posed a test case, I think the error was a problem with some edits I made to authordate1.bst (I thought I was using the original).  Using authordate2.bst with that setting in preamble solved the issue.

Comment: Great, I added an answer so can upvote/accept it. It is preferred to have answers in answers, rather than in the question, makes it easier for anyone else coming here later seeing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `natbib` with author-year styles the separator between the author and year in citations can be (re)defined by adding

```
\setcitestyle{aysep={<separator>}} %Author-Year SEParator
```

to the document preamble. In LyX this is found under Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble. The separator can be a normal space, i.e. `\setcitestyle{aysep={ }}`, if you would like a non-breaking space so that no line-break can occur between the author and the year, use `~`, i.e. `\setcitestyle{aysep={~}}`.